# mysql multiple COUNT() from multiple tables with LEFT JOIN

Tags: php, mysql

I want to show the conclusion of all users.

I have 3 tables.

**table post**

```
post_id(index)     user_id
1                  1
2                  3
3                  3
4                  4
```

**table photo**

```
photo_id(index)     user_id
1                   2
2                   4
3                   1
4                   1
```

**table video**

```
photo_id(index)     user_id
1                   4
2                   4
3                   3
4                   3
```

and in **table user**

```
user_id(index)     user_name
1                  mark
2                  tommy
3                  john
4                  james
```

in fact, it has more than 4 rows for every tables.

I want the result like this.

```
id     name      post    photo   videos
1      mark      1       2       0
2      tommy     0       1       0
3      john      2       0       2
4      james     1       1       2
5      ..        ..      ..      ..
```

Code below is SQL that can work correctly but very slow, I will be true appreciated if you help me how it using `LEFT JOIN` for it. Thanks.

## SQL

```
"select user.*, 
(select count(*) from post where post.userid = user.userid) postCount,
(select count(*) from photo where photo.userid = user.userid) photoCount,
(select count(*) from video where video .userid = user.userid) videoCount
from user order by user.id"
```

(or ORDER BY postCount, photoCount or videoCount ASC or DESC as i want )

I done researched before but no any helped me.

Comment: you should be using joins not subqueries

Comment: @Dagon . . . That is not strictly correct.  A naive approach using join's would be a very bad idea in this case.

Comment: @Dagon i thing probably use join, can you kind give me for that with `join`?

Comment: @Dagon - technically a subquery is a join is a subquery, depending on the optimizer and whether you've appropriately correlated. IMO subqueries are more intuitive in this case. Advanced optimizers can transform between the 2 depending on statistics gathering.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
    SELECT u.user_id, 
           u.user_name,
           COUNT(DISTINCT p.post_id) AS `postCount`,
           COUNT(DISTINCT ph.photo_id) AS `photoCount`,
           COUNT(DISTINCT v.video_id) AS `videoCount`
      FROM user u
 LEFT JOIN post p
        ON p.user_id = u.user_id
 LEFT JOIN photo ph
        ON ph.user_id = u.user_id
 LEFT JOIN video v
        ON v.user_id = u.user_id
  GROUP BY u.user_id
  ORDER BY postCount;
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ffa589/15)

Comment: I think this should work, but it still give wrong results for some of user rows.

Comment: @user3695637 was missing a `DISTINCT` and the sub-query will very likely be faster rather than JOIN's in this case as suggested by Gordon.

Comment: I believe that Gordon's result is faster, at least in some cases.

Answer (score 4):

Your method of doing this is quite reasonable.  Here is your query:

```
select user.*, 
       (select count(*) from post where post.userid = user.userid) as postCount,
       (select count(*) from photo where photo.userid = user.userid) as photoCount,
       (select count(*) from video where video.userid = user.userid) as videoCount
from user
order by user.id;
```

For this query, you want the following indexes:

```
post(userid)
photo(userid)
video(userid)
user(id)
```

You probably already have the last one, because `user.id` is probably the primary key of the table.

Note that a `left join` approach is a bad idea in this case.  The three tables -- posts, photos, and videos -- are independent of each other.  If a user has five of each, then joining them together would produce 125 intermediate rows.  If a user has fifty of each, it would be 125,000 -- a lot of extra processing.

Comment: yeah, i have already set it as an index before.
does it faster than join?

Comment: For the joins to work feasibly, you would need to pre-aggregate the tables in subqueries.  Your approach is very reasonable.

Comment: For one case I tried, this ran about 100 times as fast as Prix's solution.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is probably slow as it is using a correlated sub-query i.e. the sub query is running once for each user_id (unless the optimizer is doing something smart - which shouldn't be counted on).

You could use a left outer join and count or use something temporary like:

```
    SELECT u.user_id, 
           u.user_name, 
           ph.user_count AS 'photoCount', 
           p.user_count AS 'postCount', 
           v.user_count AS 'videoCount'
      FROM user u
INNER JOIN (  SELECT user_id,
                     COUNT(*) AS user_count 
                FROM photo 
            GROUP BY user_id
           ) ph
        ON ph.user_id=u.user_id
INNER JOIN (  SELECT user_id, 
                     COUNT(*) AS user_count 
                FROM post
            GROUP BY user_id
           ) p 
        ON p.user_id=u.user_id
INNER JOIN (  SELECT user_id, 
                     COUNT(*) AS user_count 
                FROM video 
            GROUP BY user_id
           ) v
        ON v.user_id=u.user_id
```

There are pros and cons for both (depending on indexes). Always have a look at the query plan (using EXPLAIN for MySQL).